# Exchange lab data population

Tags: exchange

I'm looking for a way to populate a small lab (3 servers) with email. I will be testing out some archive products and testing out Exchange 2007, but am not allowed to use my production data.

Other than using loadsim are there any datasets out there I can load into my lab. I found enrondata.org, but can only get the non-attachment dataset.

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Exchange 2007 PowerShell Scriptacular Demo pack](http://www.viveksharma.com/TECHLOG/archive/2006/12/21/announcing-the-exchange-2007-powershell-scriptacular-demo-pack.aspx) contains a number of powershell scripts to populate your exchange organisation with users and email and other useful tools, I have used them successfully to demo an Exchange product before. Make sure you configure the config file the way you want before running.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 SP1 VHD](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e99f2a96-ffbc-4323-9676-9657607c4a52) from TechNet ([64-bit version here if you are using Hyper-V](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=db31866c-2cd5-4610-8505-5f2572248618)).  IIRC, it is populated with test users and mail, and although it is time-limited (you can use it for 60 days), you can connect it to the other servers in your lab and be all set to go.

Comment: both excellent suggestions I'll try both...